# Is it Possible to Develop SPFx Application Customizers (Header+Footer) for SharePoint 2019?

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, modern-experience, 2019, applicationcustomizers

The latest supported SPFX version for SharePoint 2019 is 1.4.1. But I'm not sure what is the first SPFx version that started supporting application customizers for Header and footer. Can someone point me to the information, please?

We are trying to understend if we can develop custom Top navigation for SP2019 using SPFX. I have some douts about it. We are going to target the Modern UI only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2019 supports a version of SPFx between v1.4 and v1.4.1

So, yes extensions are indeed supported in SP 2019.

You can use the latest generator and select the option targeting 2019, it will automatically download the packages necessary for the on-prem version.

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean I don't need to install a specific version of microsoft yeoman generator? It is smart enough to use correct npm depencencies for SP 2019? If that's true - it's amazing.

Comment: You can use the latest version of the generator, its smart enough to use the correct dependencies. Quite handy, when you want to use the same code for both OnPrem and Online :)

Comment: indeed! I was thinking about setting up a separate VM or docker just to manage multiple versions. But from what I learned from you it won't be neccessary. That's really good news.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [SPFx 1.2 Release candidate was supposed to have Application customers](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes---Extensions-RC-Drop-1.2) and SPFX 1.3 got it included too. [More info here.](http://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/announcing-availability-of-sharepoint-framework-extensions-developer-preview/) It means that SPFX 1.4.1 will have Header and Footer extensions.

So creating custom headers and footers supported in SP 2019.